# Decimal for loop shell script

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, decimal

How can I define a for loop in a bash shell script in order to obtain decimal values from 0.50 to 1.00 (i.e 0.50 0.51 etc.)
I've found something like this:

```
for I in $(seq 50 100)
do
    echo $I 10 | awk '{print $1/$2}'    

done
```

But it simply shows the value, I need to assign it to a variable. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to use bc tools? Give me 5 mins i ll shoot your use case with it!

Comment: According to your code you are dividing 50 - 100 with 10 which should give you 5-10, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for I in $(seq 50 100)
do
    J=`echo $I 10 | awk '{print $1/$2}'`
    echo $J
done
```

Answer (score 6):

No need for external commands:

```
for i in {50..100} ; do
    j=0.$i
    (( i==100 )) && j=1
    echo $j
done
```

Answer (score 0):

OK here's what I've done

```
i=$(echo "scale=2;0.50" | bc)

echo $i

for a in {50..100};do
echo $i
i=$(echo "scale=2;$i+0.01" | bc)
done
```

scale = number of decimals you want
;(operations you want to do) you can / * + - ...

the output of my script is

.50
.50
.51
.52
.53
.54
.55
.56
.57
.58
.59
.60
.61
.62
.63
.64
.65
.66
.67
.68
.69 ...
1.00

Comment: 51 forks/pipes to `bc` in the loop body, UGH.

Answer (score 0):

```
seq --version
seq (GNU coreutils) 8.4
...

seq 0.5 .01 1.0
0.50
0.51
0.52
...
1.00
```